# upgrading Mobile app with different DB Architecture

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, xamarin

currenlty our app is running on SqlLite we planned to migrate to another DB provider in the next mobile app update.

Is there any best practice/Suggestion how to restore or make sure user doesn't loose any data as we are completely migrate to different DB provider

Comment: What are you doing now in the case that the user's phone is lost/stolen/reset? Are you not backing up the user's app data to some cloud/net based service already?

Answer (score 0):

You could increment the DB version in your `SQLiteOpenHelper` class and make use of the `onUpgrade()` method. There you can migrate all the data to the new DB provider and clean up the old SQLite database for good.

In subsequent releases you can remove the helper all together (as soon as you are sure you won't need the migration logic again).